# Translation for “it's a number that symbolizes how similar objects i and j are”

Tags: grammaire, traduction, vocabulaire, mathématiques

I'm looking for a correct translation of “it's a number that symbolizes how similar objects i and j are”.

What I have:

> C'est un nombre qui symbolise dans quelle mesure sont les objets i et j similaires.

I'd rather not use the word similarité, because the paragraph concerns “la matrice de dissimilarité” (the matrix of dissimilarity) and the phrase is often used, so the two would collide. I am more-or-less just trying to get a direct translation.

Comment: Ceci sonne un peu plus "naturel": C'est un nombre qui symbolise dans quelle mesure  les objets i et j sont similaires.

Comment: More context would be good, as they might be technical terms that exists already we could use.

Comment: In any case, I would use “représenter” instead of “symboliser”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation @cl-r proposes is correct and is a word-for-word transposition of your original sentence.

> C'est un nombre qui symbolise la similarité des objets *i* et *j*.

I am however of the mind that word-for-word translation are often poor or heavy. Heavy in this case. Just a hint to start making things easier on the eyes:

> Ce nombre symbolise la similarité des objets *i* et *j*.

Now, being short of context, it is hard to find the most relevant translation. I am going to make some assumptions here.

In French, "symbolize" somehow implies that the value is a symbol, an approximation. I might be wrong (though the first definition for ["symbolize" on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/symbolize) seems to support my point) but I think "symbolize" can be used in English even for precise measures. If it is the case here, I would suggest the following:

> Ce nombre mesure la similarité des objets *i* et *j*.

To accurately translate, the context is often important. What is the general area (math, physics, ...)? What number are you defining? What type of objets are *i* and *j*? Do not hesitate to give additional information rather than a raw sentence when you need help translating, as it will almost always help giving you better answers.

Comment: I edited my original question.

Answer (score 3):

> C'est un nombre qui symbolise la similarité des objets *i* et *j*.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used "*similitude*" already in your text? although it is the same structure therefore... similar..

> c'est un nombre qui represente la similitude entre *i* & *j*

might be better:

> c'est un nombre qui *[expose || montre || démontre]* l'**affinité** entre i & j.

Comment: I would avoid “démontrer” in a mathematical context, as it already has a precise meaning.